# find a holomorphic function satisfying specific equality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h$ be holomorphic function on a simply connected domain $\Omega$ with no zero in $\Omega$.Show in detail that there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$ where $h\left(z\right)=e^{g\left(z\right)}$ on $\Omega$.

Firstly, we all know that $g(z)$ should be equal to $\log z$. So for some point in $\Omega$ $z_{0}$,I think the $g(z)$ can be expressed as $\int^{z}_{z_{0}}\dfrac {1}{t}dt$. So for the rest of this problem, we should prove this function is holomorphic and satisfied the equality. But I don't know how to prove the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you mean that $g(z)$ should equal $\log (h(z))$, and that $h$ is non vanishing on $\Omega$, as otherwise the statement is not true since $\exp(z) \neq 0$. Anyway, you are right that you can construct a branch of the logarithm via $\int_{z_0}^z \frac{dt}{t}$. Now you have to take in $h$. To do so, we know that $\frac{d}{dz} \log{h(z)}$ should equal $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$, and take $g(z)=\int_{z_0}^z \frac{h'(t)}{h(t)} dt$. This is well-defined as $\Omega$ is simply connected. You now have to check that this is indeed a complex logarithm, but holomorphicity follows as you can differentiate under the integral sign, and the rest is close to the prove that $\int_{z_0}^z \frac{dt}{t}$ is a complex logarithm.